# Location of T4 templates for Razor views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to do some customizing to the T4 template used to generate code for views added using the Add View dialogue in VS 2010.  Assuming this is, in fact, done with T4 like traditionally ASPX views, where can I find this template?  I have successfully customised the ASPX template, but I can't recall where I found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The templates are located here:

```
[VS Installation Directory]\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates
```

You should copy the CodeTemplates directory and its contents into the root of your web project.

If you're using NuGet, you can simply do an `Install-Package MvcScaffold` and it will automagically do it for you.

Comment: Yeah, it's really the only way to go. Makes life so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Package MvcScaffold" added CodeTemplates folder to my project but the files included are .t4 and Views are still generated from default templates.

the solution is to change their extensions to .tt

Answer (score 1):

I have MVC 5 and I've found the templates in the following route.

```
%VS Installation Directory%\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\MvcView
```